# Django Manytomany Field for Users on facebook friend id save error

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, django-orm

I have a facebook friend table for all users, and want to have a manytomany field for User, but have run into problem on saving the data.

Here is my code:

My Model:

```
class FacebookFriend(models.Model):
user = models.ManyToManyField(User)
name = models.CharField(max_length="100", unique=False, db_index=True)
fid = models.CharField(max_length="30", unique=False, db_index=True)
birthday = models.DateTimeField(default="1776-07-04")
gender = models.CharField(max_length="10", default="NoData")
avatar = models.URLField()
```

My management:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from facepy import GraphAPI
from social_auth.signals import socialauth_registered

def facebook_friend_data(sender, user, response, details, **kwargs):

if sender == FacebookBackend:
    dict = UserSocialAuth.objects.filter(user=user.id).get()
    access_token = dict.extra_data['access_token']
    uid = dict.uid
    graph = GraphAPI(access_token)
    friends = graph.get(uid + '/friends?fields=id,name,birthday,gender,picture')

    from datetime import datetime
    from urllib2 import HTTPError

    try:
        for f in friends['data']:
            friend = FacebookFriend()
            friend.fid = f['id']
            friend.name = f['name']
            try:
                friend.gender = f['gender']
            except KeyError:
                pass
            try:
                bs= f['birthday'].split('/')
                if len(f['birthday'])==10:
                    formatted_bday= bs[2] + '-' + bs[0] + '-' + bs[1]
                else:
                    formatted_bday= '1900-' + bs[0] + '-' + bs[1]
                try:
                    friend.birthday = datetime.strptime(formatted_bday, '%Y-%m-%d')
                except ValueError:
                    pass
            except KeyError:
                pass
            friend.avatar = f['picture']
            friend.save()
            friend.user.add(user)

    except HTTPError:
        pass
socialauth_registered.connect(facebook_friend_data, sender=None)
```

My Error:

```
IntegrityError at /complete/facebook/
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "users_facebookfriend_fid_key"
```

I'm using Django Social Auth for my facebook processing.  I know the problem is in my model and how I save the data, and I'm not sure how to do that.

Thanks, and let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: did you find out the solution for this ? i'm currently facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I guess your first version of `FacebookFriend` has a `fid` field with `unique=True`. After upading model, you forget re-create your database. Further more, `manage.py syncdb` doesn't work when you change your model. Drop your exist table or database then run `manage.py syncdb` again. And there is also a fancy tool named `south` or `django-south`, can help with schema/data migration in django.